# Should I simplify the circuit or use the Kirchoff's method?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

The main goal here is to solve for the values of $I_1$, $I_2$, and $I_3$.

Should I use simplification in this circuit or should I divide this circuit into two junctions and apply Kirchoff's method? The confusing part for me is the fact that the given circuit has two voltage sources. I hope you give me ideas on what to do.

[image: Given circuit]

Comment: It can be simplified replace the two batteries with a single net .they are parallelly connected and pd directed mutually opposite. Then the 3 resistance are in parallel with this you can find the total current I2. Then use voltage relationship to do the rest

Comment: The batteries are not in parallel.  Their negative terminals are not connected directly.

Comment: There are a variety of methods to use: nodal analysis, loop analysis, superposition, Kirchoffs rules, Thevenin equivalents, Norton equivalents.It all depends on what you're comfortable with or which technique your professor wants you to demonstrate. I don't know what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only simplification I'd make, before applying Kirchhoff II, is to use Kirchhoff I to eliminate one of the three unknown currents. For example, you could rename $I_1$, calling it $I_2-I_3$. I prefer to do this on the diagram before writing down the Kirchhoff II equations, which now contain just $I_2$ and $I_3$ as the unknown currents. It saves a little time and ink – as would using "*y*" and "*z*" instead of $I_2$ and $I_3$!

No simplifications can be made to the circuit itself. For example no two resistors are in series or in parallel. You could find the currents using the superposition method instead of Kirchhoff's laws, though in my opinion it is no easier.

Comment: You *can* do a Y to $\Delta$ transform on the resistor configuration, and it does simplify calculations (no need for simultaneous equations), but I'm not sure that, overall, the method is simpler than using Kirchhoff's laws.

Answer (score 1):

One can simplify the circuit by using something called Norton equivalents for the sources. If you have a source and a series resistance (such as 24 V supply with a 6$\Omega$ resistance in series) you can replace it with a current source with $V/R$ amperes (24/6=4 A) in parallel with the same resistance.

If you do this to both sources, then you will have two parallel current sources and 3 parallel resistances. Current sources in parallel simply add, and you should know how to combine parallel resistors. Then you can reverse the conversion to get a voltage supply and equivalent resistance. That voltage will be the voltage across the middle resistor, and each of the original voltage source/series resistor branches.

This might seem like an advanced technique, but I believe it's a lot easier than solving a 3x3 system of equations. Some would call it advanced, but I call it clever and elegant.

If any of the resistors are unknown, you would have to know a current, and another technique might would better, but Norton equivalents would still be a possibility.